# How to compute the number of n-element combinations of non-negative integers with a given sum?

Tags: combinatorics

The title has the general form of the problem, but I'd also welcome insight into the following specific case: how many sets of five non-negative integers exist having a sum of 20?

I've tried breaking it down recursively, starting from the case of "How many collections of one non-negative integers summing to 20?" Only one such collection exists, containing only the number 20. I then find the number of 2 integer collections (11). But it quickly gets out of hand--I'm not certain how to go about finding the number of 3 integer collections.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The order of the numbers does not matter, and numbers may repeat. So {20,0,0,0,0} is a solution, and {0,20,0,0,0} is the same solution.

Comment: Sets or multisets? (Can a number appear more than once?). Or is it *ordered* $5$-tuples?

Comment: A number can appear more than once. Order doesn't matter. (Hence 11 results for the n=2 case.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $P(n,k)$ be the number of **partitions** of $n$ into $k$ parts, all $\ge 1$. Then (with $n=20$, $k=5$) you want $P(25,5)$. For there is in general a natural bijection between the divisions of $n$ into $k$ parts, some of which may be $0$, and the number of partitions of $n+k$ into $k$ parts, all $\ge 0$.

You can prove the following recurrence for $P(n,k)$:
$$P(n,k)=P(n-1,k-1)+P(n-k,k).$$
There is no pleasant closed form for $P(n,k)$.